# Where to put socket so PrivateTmp can be true

Tags: systemd, socket, unix-sockets

I have a C++ program which must communicate with other services (including `httpd`), and does so via a socket in `/tmp`

With the advent of `systemd` and the `PrivateTmp=true` setting, processes like httpd can no longer see my program's socket by default.  I don't want users to change the `PrivateTmp` setting of `httpd` since it's a good protection.

However, where should I put my socket file (which creates created/deleted on start/stop of my service) so that it can be shared with other processes?

(Or is the only/right solution to tell users to turn `PrivateTmp` off ??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your socket in `/var/tmp` which is a world writable dir with the sticky bit, like `/tmp`.

If your program is a daemon started by systemd you could consider using `RuntimeDirectory=somedir` in the unit file, then that dir will be created in `/run` when your unit starts, and removed when it stops. You could then create your socket in `/run/somedir/`.

Comment: ``/var/tmp`` is also hidden away by PrivateTmp. RuntimeDirectory is the way to go, possibly with socket activation.